# inconsistent interpolation of variables, format-dependent, missing interpolation after compiling into one yml via "docker-compose config"

Tags: docker-compose

We work with multiple docker-compose yml files and so far the interpolation of variables works as expected.

At a later stage in our workflow, we run `docker-compose --file one.yml --file two.yml config --no-interpolate` to compile the yml files into one.

Using the resulting file, the interpolation of variables no longer works as expected (docker-compose 1.29.2).

Repro:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
export HOST=laptop
echo
cat << 'EOF' > one.yml
services:
  repro:
    image: ubuntu:20.04
EOF

cat << 'EOF' > two.yml
services:
  repro:
    environment:
    - key1=${HOST}
    - ${HOST}=key1
    extra_hosts:
    - ${HOST}:host-gateway
    command: /bin/bash -c "echo env && env|grep key1 && echo && echo /etc/hosts && grep -v ip6 /etc/hosts &&
      if   echo && grep HOST /etc/hosts >/dev/null;
      then echo BAD /etc/hosts! && exit 1;
      else echo GOOD /etc/hosts!;
      fi"
EOF

docker-compose --file one.yml --file two.yml up
echo
docker-compose --file one.yml --file two.yml config --no-interpolate > repro.yml
docker-compose --file repro.yml up
```

Output:

```sh
./repro.sh

Starting bug2_repro_1 ... done
Attaching to bug2_repro_1
repro_1  | env
repro_1  | laptop=key1
repro_1  | key1=laptop
repro_1  | 
repro_1  | /etc/hosts
repro_1  | 127.0.0.1    localhost
repro_1  | 172.17.0.1   laptop
repro_1  | 192.168.192.2        14f5a5fa964f
repro_1  | 
repro_1  | GOOD /etc/hosts!
bug2_repro_1 exited with code 0

Recreating bug2_repro_1 ... done
Attaching to bug2_repro_1
repro_1  | env
repro_1  | ${HOST}=key1
repro_1  | key1=laptop
repro_1  | 
repro_1  | /etc/hosts
repro_1  | 127.0.0.1    localhost
repro_1  | 172.17.0.1   ${HOST}
repro_1  | 192.168.192.2        57fdabf8c1ba
repro_1  | 
repro_1  | BAD /etc/hosts!
bug2_repro_1 exited with code 1
```

https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/9213

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution but a workaround (as of docker-compose 1.29.2) is to post-process the yml that comes from `docker-compose --file one.yml --file two.yml config --no-interpolate` and change maps into lists like this:

```yaml
    environment:
      ${HOST}: key1
      key1: ${HOST}
    extra_hosts:
      ${HOST}: host-gateway
```

into

```yaml
    environment:
    - key1=${HOST}
    - ${HOST}=key1
    extra_hosts:
    - ${HOST}:host-gateway
```